# DataTables error loading ajax source data

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am getting the following error when trying to load DataTables ajax sourced data:

```
DataTables warning: table id=report-table - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7
```

Below is my DataTables html:

```
<table id="report-table" class="display nowrap" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Page ID</th>
            <th>Schema</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Last Modified</th>
            <th>Last Modified User</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Page ID</th>
            <th>Schema</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Last Modified</th>
            <th>Last Modified User</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Below is my DataTables javascript:

```
$('#report-table').DataTable({
    "ajax": data,
    "columns": [
        {
            "data": "PageId",
            "orderable": true
        },
        {
            "data": "SchemaName",
            "orderable": false
        },
        {
            "data": "Name",
            "orderable": true
        },
        {
            "data": "LastModified",
            "orderable": true
        },
        {
            "data": "LastModifiedUser",
            "orderable": true
        },
    ],
    "order": [[3, "desc"]]
});
```

Below is the confirmed json my C# controller is returning for the DataTables ajax data:

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "PageId":"foo",
         "SchemaName":"foo",
         "Name":"foo",
         "LastModified":"foo",
         "LastModifiedUser":"foo"
      },
      {
         "PageId":"foo",
         "SchemaName":"foo",
         "Name":"foo",
         "LastModified":"foo",
         "LastModifiedUser":"foo"
      },
      {
         "PageId":"foo",
         "SchemaName":"foo",
         "Name":"foo",
         "LastModified":"foo",
         "LastModifiedUser":"foo"
      }
   ]
}
```

The error seems to be related to the JSON format, but not sure what is wrong?

EDIT:

Adding full javascript code:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("button#report-form-submit").click(function () {
            event.preventDefault();
            var data = $("form#report-form").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("GetReportJson", "Report")",
                data: data,
                dataType: 'json',
                beforeSend: function (data) {
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    // Report DataTables Init
                    // ===========================================
                    $('#report-table').DataTable({
                        "ajax": data,
                        "columns": [
                            {
                                "data": "PageId",
                                "orderable": true
                            },
                            {
                                "data": "SchemaName",
                                "orderable": false
                            },
                            {
                                "data": "Name",
                                "orderable": true
                            },
                            {
                                "data": "LastModified",
                                "orderable": true
                            },
                            {
                                "data": "LastModifiedUser",
                                "orderable": true
                            },
                        ],
                        "order": [[3, "desc"]]
                    });
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                },
                complete: function (data) {
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<script>` block should look like this to initialize your data for your Data Tables:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("button#report-form-submit").click(function () {
            event.preventDefault();
            var data = $("form#report-form").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("GetReportJson", "Report")",
                data: data,
                dataType: "json",
                method: "post",
                beforeSend: function (data) {
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    // Report DataTables Init
                    // ===========================================
                    $('#report-table').DataTable({
                        "data":data,
                        "columns": [
                            {
                                "data": "PageId",
                                "orderable": true
                            },
                            {
                                "data": "SchemaName",
                                "orderable": false
                            },
                            {
                                "data": "Name",
                                "orderable": true
                            },
                            {
                                "data": "LastModified",
                                "orderable": true
                            },
                            {
                                "data": "LastModifiedUser",
                                "orderable": true
                            },
                        ],
                        "order": [[3, "desc"]]
                    });
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                },
                complete: function (data) {
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Although each answer provided good examples and feedback I think your answer is the cleanest and will be clear for others. For anyone that might run across this further reference: https://datatables.net/manual/data/.

Answer (score 1):

the data source should be an array of arrays that contains the data in the *tbody*
say

```
data = [
["foo","foo","foo","foo","foo"],
["foo","foo","foo","foo","foo"],
["foo","foo","foo","foo","foo"]
];
```

see the example [https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html][1]

additionally,  use `data: data.data` instead of `"ajax" : data`

Comment: I did notice that, but believe that format worked on other projects just fine. I know I did have to declare the column data for properties. Issue is Json.NET doesn't serialize C# objects as array of array. Is there no other work around if you cannot change format?

Comment: then you just use `data: data.data` instead of `"ajax" : data`

Comment: Udpated to "data": data.data and no longer getting original error. Now DataTables just displays "No data available in table" after the call. No console errors.

Comment: "data": data.data returns undefined. Verified my API controller response is returning json: "[{\"PageId\":\"foo\",\"SchemaName\":\"foo\",\"Name\":\"foo\",\"LastModified\":\"foo\",\"LastModifiedUser\":\"foo\"}]"

Comment: Use `data: data`. And if have any requirement change, please update it in the question and/or question's comment, instead of in the answer's comment.

Comment: @Young Shun Using and understanding the data processing logic (https://datatables.net/manual/data/) helped solved my original error. I am running into a separate issue now and which I will branch to a new question. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

As your JSON response is an object but not an array, specify the `ajax` to get the `JsonResponse.data` as below:

```js
"ajax": {
    "url": /* Your Get Data API url */,
    "dataSrc": function (json) {
        return json.data;
    },
},
```

OR

```js
"ajax": {
    "url": /* Your Get Data API url */,
    "dataSrc": "data"
},
```

> JQuery answer

**Updated: Change from `json.data` to `data` as Post Owner changed requirement.**

```
data: data
```

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "@Url.Action("GetReportJson", "Report")",
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function (data) {
    },
    success: function (data) {
        // Report DataTables Init
        // ===========================================
        $('#report-table').DataTable({
            "data": data,  
            ...  // Remaining DataTable configurations
        });
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    },
    complete: function (data) {
    }
});
```

> Output

[image]

---

**Reference**

[ajax - DataTables.net](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax)

Comment: I should have clarified the data is within jquery ajax success: function (data) callback. Editing post with full javascript code.

Comment: Hi, done update my answer. Try to use [`data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/data).

Comment: Thanks for all your help! While your updated edit in the answer is the same as the answer provided by Rahul Sharma I accepted that one as the answer since it was very clean and clear (for future refence for anyone).  Just wanted to say definitely wasn't me who downvoted your answer and not sure why it was. You have been very helpful and appreciative.